# I think I've answered a borderline off-topic question, is that answer still valid?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've just written up an answer for this question

[Scattergories program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151072/scattergories-program)

After scanning through the code and writing up my points to improve, I noticed that OP asked how to make that working as intended at all:

> I would like to add a way to either check if a word is correct, or to suggest words but it would mean I need to connect it to a dictionary of some sort (which I don't know how to do).

So that basically means their code is broken, and doesn't work as intended.

Should I rather have flagged that question for closure than answer the answerable and improvable parts of the given code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since a little re-wording would make the question on-topic (cut-out the feature request), I don't see any harm done.

Off-topic questions should not be answered. However, there's always a grey area. This question is on-topic except for a detail. Such questions can be answered as if the feature request wasn't there.

You could even edit the feature request out to improve the quality of the question, but in this case it doesn't matter much I think.

Comment: _"You could even edit the feature request out to improve the quality of the question, but in this case it doesn't matter much I think."_ I'll suggest that edit I think. THX a lot.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Unfortunatelly the edit has been rejected. Not your luckiest day I believe ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t Well, not a big deal. I just have to accustomize with my lower privs here :-P ...

Comment: I've edited out the off-topic requests in Rev 2 of the question.

Comment: @200_success THX!